# How to configure java to accept a self-signed applet without showing the confirm message

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet, self-signed

We have a web application that uses an applet to read data from a scale connected to the serial port.
This applet reads the weights and when it get three equal weights calls a javascript function to set the value in a field.

Because the applet needs to have permissions to access the serial port we did:

1. self-signed the applet with a certificate that we have created
2. Add AccessController.doPrivileged to the method that is called from javascript
3. we complete the manifest.mf with:

   Manifest-Version: 1.0

   Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.1

   Implementation-Title: Impresion de Etiquetas

   Implementation-Version: 4.0.0.0

   Bundle-Date: 2013-10-29 11:21:00 GMT-03:00

   Bundle-Version: 4.0.0.0

   Class-Path: lib/plugin.jar

   Bundle-Name: Impresion de Etiquetas

   Created-By: 1.7.0_25-b17 (Oracle Corporation)

But when open the site in firefox keeps asking if we trust the applet.

Is there any way or settings to prevent firefox showing this query every time we open the application?

This application works lika a desktop application and have access to the customers pc, so there is no problem to do some configuration on the pcs.

Comment: The user can choose to trust all apps from the same signer for a app signed with a certificate chained to a certificate authority. Maybe you don't have that option with a self-signed certificate?

Comment: i don't have that option and it show me unknow published

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manage to skip that message by adding the .pem in the java panel and adding the atribute Permissions to the manifest.mf of the applet

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way or settings to prevent firefox showing this query every time we open the application?

No, there is no way.  If there were, it would be a security bug.

And it is not FireFox but Java asking.

Comment: see also https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/updated_security_baseline_7u45_impacts for details

Comment: isn't anything to prevent this even touching the client pc? o custom browser o anythig?